How to ignore the scrollbar width when set an element's width?
I found a similar question: How to ignore a scrollbar width in CSS?, BUT:

I don't want to hide the scrollbar, I want to "ignore its width".
I don't want to use JavaScript for the process, only CSS.
I'm mainly interested in an answer that is not webkit-specific, but works across all browsers. (Or multiple solutions for different browsers could also be considered.)

In the following example, I set the width of the div to 100px. I configured it to ensure it has a scrollbar.

The expected result is currently: the div will be 100px wide and will have a scrollbar.
The actual result: the combined width of the div and the scrollbar is 100px (now div's width is 85px instead of expected 100px).
The question is, how can I ignore the width of the scrollbar when use the width: 100px; setting?




div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: scroll;
  
  /* I know this is not intended for overflow,
     I just want to illustrate that the question is
     about whether there is a similar
     native solution for the scrollbar. */
  box-sizing: content-box;
}
<div>
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
</div>



Logically, I want to achieve the same result as what box-sizing offers, but it only calculates with the border and padding sizes. Is there already an answer to this question that I just haven't searched for enough?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scrollbar-gutter

@TemaniAfif recommended a setting added in 2021 to my attention: scrollbar-gutter. This setting is already supported by most browsers, and it may soon be permanently included in Safari (currently, it is available as an experimental feature).

Make scroll bar take no space / prevent layout shift - StackOverflow

By using this property, we can ensure that the browser always reserves space for the scrollbar next to a given element, so the calculation mentioned in the question - at least in my case - becomes unnecessary, since the content will no longer jump 10-12px depending on whether the scrollbar is present or not.
My question didn't necessarily expect this solution, but it solved my problem. I have a component where I know the width (although it still includes the scrollbar-width) is fixed and won't jump. This makes calculations easier, as from now on, I'll be able to work with a "fixed" width without a scrollbar.

The image illustrates that with the appearance and disappearance of the scrollbar, the position of the content does not change.


document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  const divs = document.querySelectorAll('div');
  divs.forEach(div => {
    const fullText = 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.';
    const shortText = 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text';

    // Toggle the text content
    div.innerHTML = div.innerText === fullText ? shortText : fullText;
  });
});
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
  text-align: right;
  background: #ddd;
  margin: 1rem 0;
}

div.solution {
  overflow: auto;
  scrollbar-gutter: stable;
}
Original

<div>
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
</div>

Expected

<div class="solution">
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
</div>

<button>Toggle Text</button>



